# Where are "Property Pages" options for Web Site project in VS2017 stored?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2017

I have a web site project in Visual Studio 2017. When I right-click on the project and select "Property Pages" there are 5 sets of options (References, Build, etc). I can select "Build" and then (for example) change "Build Web Site" to "No Build". Or I can select "Start Options" and select "Use Custom Server" and set the Base Url.

But where are these options stored? A web site project does not have a .csprog file. And the choices that I make are not stored in the .sln solution file. There are other settings within the .sln related to this project (for example: "TargetFrameworkMoniker"). But it does not contain my new choices for Build or Start options.

[Edit]

The main reason that I asked this question is that it's much easier to search for information about an option, when you know the name used for storing it. It is a lot easier to search for "AspNetCompiler.Updateable " than it is to find info about "what happens when I click the checkbox for "allow this precompiled site to be updatable" in the MSBuild tab in Property Pages in Visual Studio 2017". Also the text in the GUI and even where the option is located can change more often than the programmed option name.
The fact that the .SUO file is in binary makes it more difficult to find out info about those options.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Settings for a Web Site project are split between the solution file (*.sln) and the solution user options file (.suo).

Solution files are meant to be checked into source control, so setting shared among your development team will go here, such as target framework version, references, etc.

User options settings are local to your machine and will be stored in a .suo file.  Older versions of VS placed this file next to the *.sln file, but now it lives in the .vs hidden folder next to the solution file (e.g. `.vs\WebProjectName\v15.suo`).  This is a binary file type, and not meant to be edited by hand.

Finally, any server settings for IIS Express based projects are now saved in the `.vs\config\applicationHost.config` file.

Comment: I changed some project settings ("no build" to "Build Web Site", Target Framework from .NET 4.0 to 3.5 and some changes in Start Options). I saved, exited VS and checked which of the files you mention changed. It is an IIS Express project, but applicationHost.config did not change. .SUO did change, but as you said it is binary, so I couldn't see the changes. Since all the changes were stored in the .SUO file, is it true to say then, that all the Property Pages options for a WebSite are considered just local user options and do not travel with the project?

Comment: Target Frameworks should be in the .sln file, as well as any project-to-project references your website might have. I think everything else from the property pages does end up in the .suo.

Comment: Yes, the target framework setting ended up in the .sln - even though this website is not using .NET. The MSBuild tab options also go into the .sln.

Answer (score 2):

> Where are “Property Pages” options for Web Site project in VS2017 stored?

After a full-text search website name of my entire hard drive, I found those setting in:

```
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\WebsiteCache\Websites.xml.
```

Note: Since this is a cache file, you should close Visual Studio before you check the latest settings about website.

Comment: The settings may end up in a cache file, but one couldn't say that this is where VS stores them.